# Physics & derivatives written in a weird way

Tags: differentiation

I was always taught that $\frac d {dx} (\ln x) = \frac 1 x$. No derivative had as a result any $dx$ words.
In a physics book I encountered something like this (error discussion) [there might be a little difference, as I don't have the book right now]:

We have $\ln a + \ln b = \ln c$. So after deriving both sides we get $\frac {da} a + \frac {db}b = \frac {dc}c $

Why is this small difference $da, db, dc$ put in there? Why isn't it $\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac 1c $ ? And what are we differentiating in reference to? $x$, $a$ or what?

Another example [this is exactly like this]: We have 
$[(\frac 1 {S_1}+\frac 1 {S_2})\rho g V + p_0]V = nRT$. Let's treat V as a function of T and differentiate both sides wrt T. Then we have

$2(\frac 1 {S_1}+\frac 1 {S_2})\rho g V \frac {dV} {dT} + p_0 \frac {dV} {dT} = nR$

Once again, why are we adding this difference quotient $\frac {dV} {dT}$? Is this as the derivative of the internal function?

Comment: cf. [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_differentiation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding your first question, note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln c = \frac{1}{c}\frac{dc}{dx}$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{a}\frac{da}{dx} + \frac{1}{b}\frac{db}{dx} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{dc}{dx}$$

Then, as physicists often do, 'cancel' the $dx$ on both sides to yield

$$\frac{da}{a} +  \frac{db}{b} = \frac{dc}{c}$$

Regarding your second question, it is stated that $V = V(t)$ thus it is elementary that

$$\frac{d}{dt}KV(t) = K\frac{dV}{dt}$$

Comment: Compare the comment on the Jim's answer - why can we cancel out the $dx$ when the derivative (the first equation is clearly a derivative of a compound function) is not a ratio?

Comment: @marmistrz, from the Taylor series, we know that $$f(x + dx) = f(x) + f'(x)dx$$  So, formally, for the log function, this is $$\ln(x + dx) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{x}dx$$  or  $$\ln(x + dx) - \ln(x) = d\, \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: @marmistrz in physics, derivatives _are_ viewed as ratios of small changes in the limit as the size of the change goes to zero. The functions we work with are generally well-behaved enough that this is valid.

Comment: You may prefer to think of this as simply a shorthand notation, in which $da$ really means $da/dx$.  It's just another step onwards from writing what should strictly be $c(x)$ as $c$.

Answer (score 8):

The reason you see the $da$, $db$, or $dc$ is precisely because it isn't specified what the derivative is taken with respect to. What happens is the following:

First, they write the differential element of the logarithmic function:

$$d\,\ln f=\frac{df}{f}$$

This is always true no matter what function $f$ is. When we take a derivative with respect to some parameter $q$, we get:

$$\frac{d\,\ln f(q)}{dq}=\frac{1}{f(q)}\frac{df(q)}{dq}$$

So if $q=x$ and $f(q)=q$ then this becomes:

$$\frac{d\ln x}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$

For your second example, the original equation was differentiated wrt $T$. Since, apparently in this case, only $V$ and $T$ itself were dependent on $T$, they are the only terms that get differentiated. $\frac{dT}{dT}=1$ and $\frac{dV^2}{dT}=2V\frac{dV}{dT}$. That's about it

Comment: But I was taught that the derivative itself is not a ratio, although it graphically looks like a ratio. So why can we multiply by $df$ in the first equation?

Comment: @marmistrz because that is a differential element, not a complete derivative. It is a way of representing a derivative. Since it looks like a ratio, we can write it this way to mean that this is a derivative where we have not yet specified what it is taken wrt yet. Alternatively, it also can be used for integration in this form

Answer (score 7):

Using $V=V(T)$, taking the other terms as constant and working backwards from the result you gave, I suspect your equation of state actually reads
$$
nRT = \left[ \left( \frac 1{S_1} + \frac 1{S_2} \right)\rho gV + p_0\right]\cdot V = \left( \frac 1{S_1} + \frac 1{S_2} \right)\rho gV^2 + p_0V
$$
In that case, $dV/dT$ is just notation for the derivative and you get to your result by using the chain rule, specifically
$$
\frac {d}{dT}V^2 = (V^2)' = 2VV' = 2V\frac{dV}{dT}
$$
You can't quite interpret the other example that way.

One way to look at it is to just think of $\mathrm d$ as the 'infinitesimal' version of $\Delta$. In particular, if $\Delta a$ is small enough, we have
$$
\Delta\ln a = \ln(a+\Delta a)-\ln a = \frac{\Delta a}a+\text{something very small}
$$
and symbolically for $\Delta a\to0$
$$
\mathrm d\ln a = \frac{\mathrm da}a
$$

A second way to look at your example is to regard $a,b,c$ as functions of a parameter $\lambda$. Then, differentiating
$$
\ln a + \ln b = \ln c
$$
with regards to that parameter yields (again by chain rule)
$$
\frac {a'}a + \frac {b'}b = \frac {c'}c
$$
The third way to look at this expression comes from differential geometry and requires the notion of [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

The first step on the way is to realize that derivatives are actually linear maps, so for a function $f$, its derivative $f'$ should actually be considered a $1\times1$ matrix.

You can expand a matrix in terms of its basis and dual basis, ie
$$
(a_{ij}) = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} \mathbf e_i\otimes \mathbf e_j^*
$$

For functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the target space in 1-dimensional and we can drop the sum over $i$ as well as the basis vectors $\mathbf e_i$. Then, for reasons I won't get into here, we rename $\mathbf e_1^*$ to $\mathrm dx$ and arrive at
$$
\mathrm df = (f') = f'\mathrm dx
$$
where the second term is said $1\times1$ matrix.