# differentials in physics

Tags: differentiation

Often I find the following expressions in physics books:
Say we have a current density $\vec{j}=\rho\vec{v}$ through a surface $\vec{F}$ of particles $N$ in the volume $V$ with the density $\rho=dN/dV$ and -for simplicity- the velocity $\vec{v}\,||\,d\vec{F}$, $\vec{v}=d\vec{s}/dt$. Now one writes
$$ \rho\vec{v}=\frac{dN}{dV}\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt}=\frac{dN}{dsdF}\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt}=\frac{dN}{dFdt}\hat{s}$$
with 
    $$ \vec{j}\cdot\vec{dF}=\frac{dN}{dt}$$.
My question: Shouldn't one rather write $\frac{d^2N}{dFdt}\hat{s}$ since $N(V,t)$?
The same appears in expressions like
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j}=-\frac{1}{dV}\frac{dN}{dt}=-\frac{1}{dt}\frac{dN}{dV}=-\frac{d\rho}{dt}$$
which is the continuity equation. Of course in the latter $N$ is infinitesimally small quantity since $N(dV)$. From the physical point of view it makes perfectly sense but from the mathematical form it looks inconsistent. How to cure it?

Comment: $F$ is a 2-D surface, so by your logic you could equally well say that it should be $d^3 N/dx dy dt$ or something like that instead.  (Not that I'm saying that you *should* say that, mind you.)

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154373/physics-derivatives-written-in-a-weird-way?rq=1

Comment: @Virgo: I have no problem with differentials, I have a problem with the inconsistent treatment of them in physics as shown above.

Comment: As mentioned by a commentator in that link, in physics differentials are usually treated as small perturbations. This doesn't cause any problems, in general, due to the well behaved nature of the functions considered.

Comment: @Virgo: Sounds like a cheap excuse. One part of my question was: Shouldn't it be $d^2N/(dFdt)$ . This  concerns also "well behaved" functions. The same holds for this strange looking expression $1/dV\cdot dN/dt$: The limit $V \rightarrow 0$ cannot be taken independently for $(dN(V)/dt)$ and $1/\Delta V$ but it has the appearance.

Comment: I think this is really just a matter of taste. Most notation need to omit some information and so one has to rely on the reader keeping in mind certain facts which aren't explicitly stated.